# Как настроить ssh для доступа с виндовс на виртуалку линукс

Tags: linux, сеть, ssh, virtualbox, nat

Ситуация:
Есть стационарный компьютер на котором установлена ОС Windowc, на винде установлен VirtualBox. На виртуал бокс установлен Linux Ubuntu server.

Подскажите какие нужно сделать настройки в линукс(виртуалка) и виндовс для того чтобы можно было с винды подключаться к виртуалке ubuntu server по ssh и при этом чтобы на виртуалке был интернет!!!

P.S. облазил весь нет, пробовал много разных способов, ничего не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос.
Для того чтобы осуществить подключение по ssh с Windows(основная система на компьютере) к виртуальной машине ubuntu server на виртуал бокс, необходимо:

1. Зайти в сетевые подключения
2. найти сетевой адаптер VirtualBox
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Кликнуть правой кнопкой на него - нажать Состояние - нажать Сведения
4. Посмотреть какой указан адрес в IPv4
5. Открыть настройки виртуальной машины - вкладка Сеть
6. Раскрыть дополнительно - нажать проброс портов
7. Добавить новое правило проброски портов
8. Сделать так как показано на скрине
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
9. Подтвердить внесенные изменения нажав Ок
10. Теперь вы можете подключаться по ssh введя адрес адаптера

Comment: Вместо адреса хоста проще набрать просто 127.0.0.1

Comment: зачем проброс? не понятно просто посмотрите адрес виртуалки и подключайтесь

Comment: А можно просто сделать сетевой мост в настройках виртуалки и не париться.

Comment: делал сетевой мост, тогда нет доступа в нет

Comment: смотрел адрес виртуалки, не получается например через путти указав адрес виртуалки подключиться